# Hugging face whoami endpoint returns unauthorized

Tags: curl, huggingface-transformers

Can't make `/whoami` endpoint of hugging face API work. I'm using `curl` and pass a token that I've got from the UI in the `Authorization` header.

```
$ curl https://huggingface.co/api/whoami -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"
> { "error": "Unauthorized" }
```

At the same time I can use the same token to get private models

```sh
$ curl https://huggingface.co/api/models/private/model -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>"
> {"id": "private/model", "modelId": "private/model", ...}
```

Is there something I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for raising this!

The endpoint was updated to `whoami-v2`, it seems we missed updating that doc page. Here is a working example

```
curl https://huggingface.co/api/whoami-v2 -H "Authorization: Bearer your_token"
```

Note that we also have a Python library with a `whoami` method you can use if that's useful. https://github.com/huggingface/huggingface_hub/tree/main/src/huggingface_hub

Comment: Still returns `Unauthorized` with the organization tokens, the ones that start with `api_`.

Comment: Turns out, the endpoint doesn't work with the old organization tokens(don't know exactly how old, mine was issued about 6 months ago), but works alright with the fresh ones.